# Trying to highlight current nav icon with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the current navigation icon on my site. It's made more complex as apart from the blog section, all other nav links go to different sections on the same page. I want the home icon to be highlighted in all instances unless the user is on my blog section. I have used CSS to set opacity of the icon to 0.5, and to highlight the icon a class is added using JQuery the changes opacity to 1. I'm almost there, however when the user goes to my blog section and then back to home section, the icon doesn't highlight (unless I refresh browser). Here is my JQuery:

```
 // change opacity of nav icons
    $('#nav-home, #nav-port, #nav-exp, #nav-cont, #nav-blog').hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
        }, function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
    });

    // highlight current nav icon
    var queryString = location.search.replace('?','').split('=');

    $('#nav-blog').bind('load click', function(){
        if(queryString[1] == 'blog-home' || queryString[0] == 'article')
            $(this).addClass('nav-current');
        });

    $('#nav-home, #nav-port, #nav-exp, #nav-cont').bind('load click', function(){
        if(queryString[1] == 'home' || !queryString[1])
            $('#nav-home').addClass('nav-current');
    });
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Sorry! Here is my site http://www.jonhudsonweb.com

EDIT: Figured it out!! But I'm not allowed to answer my question yet as I'm not good enough :(

Here's my solution:

```
 // highlight current nav icon
        var queryString = location.search.replace('?','').split('=');

        $(window).bind('load unload', function(){
            if(queryString[1] == 'blog-home' || queryString[0] == 'article')
                $('#nav-blog').addClass('nav-current');
            });

        $(window).bind('load unload', function(){
            if(queryString[1] == 'home' || !queryString[1])
                $('#nav-home').addClass('nav-current');
        });
```

+1 for me!

Yay.

Comment: Oddly, posting your 'answer' in the 'question' doesn't count as answering. Please post the answer *as* an answer, and then accept that (I think it'll be a couple of days before you *can* accept it, but even so...), then people *can* +1 your answer.

Comment: Hi David, thanks, yes I did try to answer my question originally but I wasn't allowed. Apparently I have to wait 8 hours! But I assure you I will answer my question properly when I can. It will be my first accepted answer! Bit sad really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
// highlight current nav icon
    var queryString = location.search.replace('?','').split('=');

    $(window).bind('load unload', function(){
        if(queryString[1] == 'blog-home' || queryString[0] == 'article')
            $('#nav-blog').addClass('nav-current');
        else 
            $('#nav-home').addClass('nav-current');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Jon, your solution looks a little awkward to me. Why not add an `.active` class to the icon you want to appear constantly active, and style that with CSS?

Furthermore, you should really use a class that unites all the navigation icons, and reference that class for your `.hover()` method, as opposed to listing out each ID. Coincidentally, I'm doing the same thing on [my site](http://jezenthomas.com).

Comment: Hi Jezen, thanks for your input. I agree with your second suggestion, can't believe I didn't think of that. However I'ma  bit confused by your first suggestion. I think that is what I'm doing? I have a css class called "nav-current", and I'm applying that using JQuery, to whichever of the two icons (home or blog) I want to appear active. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: You're right, that is what you're doing and I should have been clearer. I just mean it's probably slightly more elegant to do this server-side with PHP or something. And, thanks very much :)

Comment: Ah I see. Interesting, I didn't think of that. Thanks!